# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (5,1) into shape (0,1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am working on a time series forecasting project using Python, and I am running into an issue with broadcasting arrays. Specifically, I am getting the following error:

`ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (5,1) into shape (0,1)`

This error occurs in the following line of code in my forecast function:

`output_predict[-future_day + i : -future_day + i + out_logits.shape[1], :] = out_logits[-1, :, 0].reshape(-1, 1)`

Here, output_predict is a NumPy array of shape (281, 1), and out_logits is a NumPy array of shape (1, 5, 1). I am trying to assign the values of out_logits to a slice of output_predict, but I am getting a broadcasting error.

I have tried to reshape the out_logits array using out_logits[-1, :, 0].reshape(-1, 1), but this doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Whole code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm
from datetime import timedelta

def forecast():
    modelnn = Model(
        learning_rate, num_layers, df_log.shape[1], size_layer, df_log.shape[1], dropout_rate
    )
    
    date_ori = pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[:, 0]).tolist()
    
    pbar = tqdm(range(epoch), desc = 'train loop')
    for i in pbar:
        total_loss, total_acc = [], []
        for k in range(0, df_train.shape[0] - 1, timestamp):
            index = min(k + timestamp, df_train.shape[0] - 1)
            batch_x = np.expand_dims(df_train.iloc[k : index, :].values, axis = 0)
            batch_y = df_train.iloc[k + 1 : index + 1, :].values
            batch_y = np.expand_dims(batch_y, axis=0)
            modelnn.model.train_on_batch(batch_x, batch_y)
            logits = modelnn.model.predict_on_batch(batch_x)
            loss = np.mean((batch_y - logits)**2)
            total_loss.append(loss)
            total_acc.append(calculate_accuracy(batch_y[:, 0], logits[:, 0]))
        pbar.set_postfix(cost = np.mean(total_loss), acc = np.mean(total_acc))
    
    future_day = test_size

    output_predict = np.zeros((df_train.shape[0] + future_day, df_train.shape[1]))
    output_predict[0] = df_train.iloc[0]
    upper_b = (df_train.shape[0] // timestamp) * timestamp

    for k in range(0, (df_train.shape[0] // timestamp) * timestamp, timestamp):
        out_logits = modelnn.model.predict(
            np.expand_dims(df_train.iloc[k : k + timestamp], axis = 0)
        )
        output_predict[k + 1 : k + timestamp + 1] = out_logits

    if upper_b != df_train.shape[0]:
        out_logits = modelnn.model.predict(
            np.expand_dims(df_train.iloc[upper_b:], axis = 0)
        )
        output_predict[upper_b + 1 : df_train.shape[0] + 1] = out_logits
        future_day -= 1
        date_ori.append(date_ori[-1] + timedelta(days = 1))
    
    for i in range(future_day):
        o = output_predict[-future_day - timestamp + i:-future_day + i]
        out_logits = modelnn.model.predict(np.expand_dims(o, axis = 0))

        print("output_predict shape:", output_predict.shape)
        print("out_logits shape:", out_logits.shape)

        output_predict[-future_day + i : -future_day + i + out_logits.shape[1], :] = out_logits[-1, :, 0].reshape(-1, 1)
        date_ori.append(date_ori[-1] + timedelta(days = 1))
    
    deep_future = anchor(output_predict[:, 0], 0.4)
    
    return deep_future
```

Error with output:

```
simulation 1
train loop: 100%|██████████| 300/300 [04:04<00:00,  1.23it/s, acc=97.3, cost=0.00281]
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 201ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 23ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 16ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 17ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 16ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 16ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 17ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 16ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 17ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 16ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 17ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 17ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 20ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 16ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 16ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 17ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 16ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 187ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
output_predict shape: (281, 1)
out_logits shape: (1, 5, 1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-f5aa569f2292> in <cell line: 2>()
      2 for i in range(simulation_size):
      3     print('simulation %d'%(i + 1))
----> 4     results.append(forecast())

<ipython-input-8-8b7d2e1d0170> in forecast()
     53         print("out_logits shape:", out_logits.shape)
     54 
---> 55         output_predict[-future_day + i : -future_day + i + out_logits.shape[1] + 1, :] = out_logits[-1, :, 0].reshape(-1, 1)
     56         date_ori.append(date_ori[-1] + timedelta(days = 1))
     57 

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (5,1) into shape (6,1)
```

Comment: Please provide a full stack trace of the error.

Comment: Updated question, included whole output